# herokuにwebアプリをデプロイしたいのですが途中でエラーが出てうまくいきません。

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, heroku

herokuにwebアプリをデプロイしたいのですが途中でエラーが出てうまくいきません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ECONNRESET: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 69.172.201.153:82
これは指定したポートがいけないのでしょうか？

Comment: 途中でプロキシを設定しているようですが、こちらは必須ですか？エラーもこのプロキシに関連したもののように見えます。 / 可能であれば ”プロキシ無し” の状態で試してみてください。

Comment: CLIがdeprecatedである旨の警告が多く見えます。まずはHerokuのCLIを更新してみるのはどうでしょうか。